# NService bus 'Publish()' base interface not sending concrete child class properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, nservicebus

I am using an interface to send message to a handler using NServicebus. Below is the interface:

```
interface IDeliveryTarget
{
        public DeliveryType DeliveryType { get; }
        public string DocumentId { get; set; }
}
```

Child Classes Email and Fax:

```
class EmailTarget : IDeliveryTarget
{
    public DeliveryType DeliveryType => DeliveryType.Email;
    public int DocumentId {get;set;}
    public string MessageBody { get; set; }
    public string[] Recepients { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
}
class FaxTarget : IDeliveryTarget
{
    public DeliveryType DeliveryType => DeliveryType.Email;
    public int DocumentId {get;set;}
    public string FaxNumber { get; set; }
    public string FaxUserName { get; set; }
    public string Organization { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
}
```

I send `List<IDeliveryTarget>` from handler as below:

```
context.Publish(new UploadSuccess
{
   DeliveryTargets = new List<IDeliveryTarget>()
}
```

This list has many Email and Fax inputs.

Handled in another Saga as below:

```
public async Task Handle(UploadSuccess message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
```

But here the UploadSuccess message has only properties defined in IDeliveryTarget interface but Email and Fax specific properties are missing.

I except Email and Fax properties to be present for further processing.
Please guide.

Comment: First, i don't think that `EmailTarget` and `FaxTarget` are Child classes as you mention it.
Second you are defining a `List<IDeliverTarget>` and i would like to think that the property `DeliveryTargets` in `publish function

Comment: @SomarZein and your solution to the issue?

Comment: You should at some point store the right type `EmailTarget` in variable from type `IDeliveryTarget` then convert it back to orginal type when you needed it.
somthing like this `IDeliveryTarget = new EmailTarget()`.

Comment: When I create the object IDeliveryTarget that's how am doing it.

Comment: Sorry, the first comment was posted before i finished changing.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution to what @MindSwipe mentioned is to have dedicated properties on the event for each of the concrete types ie.:

```cs
context.Publish(new UploadSuccess
{
   EmailTargets = new List<EmailTarget>(),
   FaxTargest = new List<FaxTarget>();
}
```

This will allow you to access concrete types' properties in a handler without the need for casting.

Comment: Last option, I will do this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the items in `DeliveryTarget` to a concrete implementation of your interface, those properties are still there, they're just hidden to intellisense because you have a variable of type `IDeliveryTarget` which doesn't declare those properties you want.

Do something like this:

```cs
public async Task Handle(UploadSuccess message, IMessageHandlerContext ctx)
{
    foreach (IDeliveryTarget target in message.DeliveryTargets)
    {
        if (target is EmailTarget emailTarget)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Got email target with subject {emailTarget.Subject}");
        }
        else if ( ... )
    }
}
```

This becomes cumbersome with lots of implementations, I'd suggest you add a method like `Handle` to the `IDeliveryTarget` interface and use polymorphism to shorten that to:

```cs
public async Task Handle(UploadSuccess message, IMessageHandlerContext ctx)
{
    foreach (IDeliveryTarget target in message.DeliveryTargets)
        await target.Handle();
}
```

Comment: This isn't the case unfortunately. Somehow only interface props are being sent. `if (target is EmailTarget emailTarget)` fails.

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"? Is an exception thrown? Does the List actually contain instances of `EmailTarget`? If you set a breakpoint before the loop and inspect `message.DeliveryTargets` what objects are inside it (of which type are they)?

Comment: By fails I meant if condition for EmailTarget is false. It shows of type DeliveryTarget_Impl something.